# Click on random link in webpage using selenium API for python

Tags: python, selenium, random, hyperlink, html

How can I click on random link on a given webpage using selenium API for python. ? 
I'm using python 2.7.
Thanks

Comment: Why on earth do you need to click a random link? Where's the value in doing that?

Comment: @Arran it's useful for automatic traffic generation task

Comment: I need for checking if frame was refreshed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

find_elements_by_tagname() will surely work. There is another option also. You can use find_elements_by_partial_link_text where you can pass empty string.

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> from random import randint

>>> driver = webdriver.Firefox()
>>> driver.get('http://www.python.org')

>>> links = driver.find_elements_by_partial_link_text('')
>>> l = links[randint(0, len(links)-1)]
>>> l.click()
```

Comment: @ thanks. It helped. I was using **choice** method for getting random item of list e.g. `l = choice(links)` after importing **choice** from **random** module

Comment: I wish I could see you answer half year a ago!

Answer (score 1):

```html
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hhR3DwzV2eA')


# store the current url in a variable
current_page = driver.current_url

# create an infinite loop
while True:
    try:
        # find element using css selector
        links = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.content-link.spf-link.yt-uix-sessionlink.spf-link')

        # create a list and chose a random link
        l = links[randint(0, len(links) - 1)]

        # click link
        l.click()

        # check link
        new_page = driver.current_url

        # if link is the same, keep looping
        if new_page == current_page:
            continue
        else:
            # break loop if you are in a new url
            break
    except:
        continue
```

Creating a list work, but if you are having problems like me use this code if you keep getting Timeout Error or your webdriver isn't consistently clicking the link.

As an example I used a YT video. Say you want to click a recommended video on the right side, well, it has a unique css selector for those links.

The reason why you want to make an infinite loop is b/c when when you make a list of elements, for some reason, python doesn't do a good job expressing stored elements. Be sure you have a catch all 'except' b/c you will get Timeout Errors and such and you want to force it to click on the random link.

Answer (score 0):

How about generating a list of all available links on the page and then clicking a random element from within that list?

```
list = driver.find_elements_by_tagname("a")
list[random.Random(0, len(list)].click()
```

(I hope that's how you use random in python 2.7, I'm a python 3.3 user, sorry)